# Residues at infinity to compute an integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I am interested in computing the integral of 
$$ \frac{1}{(z-10)(z^4+2)}$$
along the circle centered at 0 with radius 5. I would like to use the theorem that the sum of all the residues of a function is 0, but this would require me to compute the residue at infinity. I know this function has a zero (of order 5) at infinity, but can I conclude it does not have a residue? My book says for example the residue of $1/z$ at infinity is $-1$ and not 0, so presumably one can not have a singularity at infinity but still have residue.

Comment: You should do the full Laurent series up to the residue term (I guess $x^4$ should be $z^4$)

Comment: Under what conditions can I conclude the residue at infinity is zero?

Comment: is there a specific reason you want to use that specific theorem?

Comment: Just want to get some practice in, that's all.

Comment: If you want to be able to say $\sum_k Res(f(z),a_k)+Res(f(z),\infty) = 0$ then you need $Res(f(z),\infty)=-Res(\frac{f(1/z)}{z^2},0)$ as the definition of the residue at $\infty$. This is because $\sum_k Res(f(z),a_k) = \frac{1}{2i \pi} \lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{|z| = R} f(z) dz =\frac{1}{2i \pi} \lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{|s| = 1/R} f(1/s)\frac{ds}{s^2} = Res(\frac{f(1/z)}{z^2},0)$

Answer (score 1):

For $R>10$ you get via substitution $z=Rw$
$$
\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{(z-10)(z^4+2)}=\oint_{|w|=1}\frac{R\,dw}{R^5(w-\frac{10}R)(w^4+\frac2{R^4})}
$$
where you have a factor of $R^{-4}$ that tends to zero while simultaneously the integral converges to $\oint_{|w|=1}\frac{dw}{w^5}=0$.

This does not even use the Cauchy integral theorem which tells us that all those integrals have the same value independent of $R>10$ which is zero.

So indeed the task can be solved by computing the residuum at $z=10$.

Answer (score 0):

If a function $f$ has zero of order $n>1$ at infinity, then it has res$[f,\infty]=0.$ For large $|z|$
\begin{gather*}
f(z)=\frac{1}{z^n}\varphi(z), \quad \exists\lim_{z\to\infty}\varphi(z)=\varphi(\infty)\neq0;\\
\varphi(z)=\varphi(\infty)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{z^k}, \; \text{for large } \; |z|.
\end{gather*}
Hence $res[f,\infty]=0.$ The function $1/z$ has non-zero residue at infinity exactly for this reason. The res$[\frac{1}{z^2},\infty]=0.$